# Python 3 Connection Timed Out for Parser

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib, python-3.3

I have a parsing program that scrapes together a lot of information from online and prints it out using Python 3. When I say a lot I mean the program scrapes from a few hundred different web pages. Anyways, when I run it, it usually encounters the error

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Sometimes it's before the before anything is printed out, sometimes it's mid, and sometimes the program goes through entirely without a hitch. I've tried it on my laptop that connects to wifi and my desktop that's hooked up to ethernet. I was wondering if anyone had similar issues or a helpful suggestion as to why it does that. I know it would only have to be general suggestions because I don't have my file included.

For specifics here are my imports:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I'd include my file but it's a pretty big program. Thanks for your help!